# Php MySQl DATE format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have created MySQL table, and I have created **DATE**, not **DATETIME** format..
Now when I store some date in that table, I see the date in PhpMyAdmin like this:

```
DATE
2015-01-08
```

But when I try to read date with Php, I only get date output like this:

```
01 01 1970
```

The Php code is:

```
date('m d Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: It really says "DATE 2015-01-08" and not just "2015-01-08"? You need to remove "DATE " first then.

Comment: You get date output in that format because that's the format (`'m d Y'`) that you've asked for.

Comment: did you confirm that `$row['date']` actually contains `2015-01-08`?

Comment: If it is really returning the wrong date, then you have not included the relevant part of your code. If it is actually returning the correct date, but just isn't formatting it like you want it to, please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#example-2404) to learn about date formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine -

```
$mysqlDate = '2015-01-08';
$phpDate = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($mysqlDate));
echo $phpDate;
```

returns '01-08-2015'. Check what you're returning in `$row['date']`, it is likely empty.